# Two same programs different outputs?

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=5, y=4, z;
        int step1 = (++x + ++y);
        int step2 = (y++ % 2);
        z= step1*step2;
        System.out.println(step1 + "*" + step2);
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

This program prints `11`. I tried inlining `step1` and `step2` expecting to get the same result but it prints `1` instead.

```
package com.company;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=5, y=4, z;
        z= (++x + ++y) * y++ % 2;
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Why is the output different?

Comment: Try `z = (++x + ++y) * (y++ % 2);`

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you take a look at how java does its [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

To have your same output, just change your code in the second example to

```
z = (++x + ++y) * (y++ % 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has problem. In java it's working like this.

```java
   z= ((++x + ++y) * y++) % 2;
```

calculation are
`z = ((6 + 5) * 5) % 2`
`z = (55) % 2` 
`z = 1`

for your expected answer, you need to write

```java
   z= (++x + ++y) * (y++ % 2);
```

now (z = 11)